# Error when using mutate_if or mutate(across()) to convert all columns from character to numeric

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

For my learning objective, I would appreciate if someone could correct *and* explain why neither of these two solutions work

Let's say I have

```
str(b)
tibble [3 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Intensity.DISEASE5: chr [1:3] "27.37" ...
 $ Intensity.DISEASE6: chr [1:3] "27.47" ...
 $ Gene.names        : chr [1:3] "IGLL5;IGLC1"  ...
```

I want to convert all columns to numeric values `as.numeric` except for the character values in `b$Gene.names`.

I tried

```
b %>% mutate_if((str_detect(colnames(.), "Intensity") & is.character), as.numeric)
```

> Error in str_detect(colnames(.), "Intensity") & is.character :
> operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types

And

```
b %>% mutate(across(where(contains("Intensity")), as.character))
```

> Error in `mutate()`: ! Problem while computing `..1 = across(where(contains("Intensity")),   as.character)`. Caused by error
> in `across()`: ! Can't convert `fn`, an integer vector, to a function.

Data

```
b <- structure(list(Intensity.DISEASE5 = c("27.3736820220947", "23.7670879364014", 
"24.8043975830078"), Intensity.DISEASE6 = c("27.4711933135986", 
"26.1416263580322", "25.3245735168457"), Gene.names = c("IGLL5;IGLC1", 
"QSOX1", "GFRA2")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you do not need the `dplyr::where()` function when using `dplyr::contains()`... though as @DarranTsai pointed out in the comment, you might want to use it in combination to restrict the selection further (not only part of the column name but also data type):

```
library(dplyr)

b %>% dplyr::mutate(dplyr::across(dplyr::contains("Intensity"), as.character)) 
# you could use as.numeric or even readr::parse_number instead of as.character to convert to a numeric data type
```

about the `dplyr::mutate_if()` you should not worry, since acording to the [documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate_all.html) "[...] Scoped verbs (⁠_if⁠, ⁠_at⁠, ⁠_all⁠) have been superseded by the use of across() in an existing verb [...]"

Comment: `where()` is needed. I.e. `b %>% mutate(across(contains("Intensity") & where(is.character), as.numeric))`

Comment: @DarrenTsai thanks for the input. I just saw that the mutate_if() part has distinct requirements to the across() part in OPs question - anyhow the test data and original question make the use of where(is.character) redunant as the columns to convert are character and the column not to convert does not contain the search string.

Comment: Yes for the test data `Intensity.DISEASE5` and `Intensity.DISEASE6` are character. But for a general purpose, if there is a column, say `Intensity.DISEASE7` that is numeric, then `across(contains("Intensity"), as.numeric)` also catches it and converts it into numeric. Obviously this conversion is redundant. Inserting `where(is.character)` in `across` will skip this column and improve efficiency.